# How do I specify key/value pairs to rust log subsystem?

Tags: rust

I have a struct which contains a log_context, comprised of a vector of `kv pairs`. I'd like to `log` this, in addition to the normal logging. For example:

```
struct Something {
    server_addr: String,
    client_id: usize,
    log_context: Vec<(log::kv::Key<'static>, log::kv::Value<'static>)>,
}
impl Something {
    fn new(server_addr: String, client_id: usize) -> Self {
        let server_addr_value = log::kv::Value::from_display(&server_addr);
        Self {
            server_addr,
            client_id,
            log_context: vec![
                ("address".into(), server_addr_value),
                ("client_id".into(), log::kv::Value::from_display(&client_id))
                ]
        }
    }
}
```

later, I'd like to log as:

```
use kv_log_macro::info;
info!(
    "Something to log",
    &something.log_context,
)
```

I know I can provide this as:

```
info!(
    "Something to log", {
        address: something.server_addr,
        client_id: something.client_id
});
```

However, that seems like a maintenance nightmare when I later refactor and want to log another field in `Something`. Is there a way to accomplish my goal without having to write custom macros?

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://docs.rs/kv-log-macro/1.0.7/src/kv_log_macro/lib.rs.html), it is only considering key-value pairs in the `{ key : value }` syntax. I would suggest making a feature request to support `{ ..something.log_context }` for example, but unfortunately the repo doesn't look too active. You'll probably have to make custom macros.

Comment: I filed an enhancement request/issue, we'll see how it goes. In the mean time I'll try making new macros.